# Black screen after resume (background to foreground) event phonegap android

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, resume, onpause

I have a problem with my phonegap app (made with ionic) in android. When i pause the app (pushing the home button for instance) and then when i come back to my app, it display a black screen few seconds before app content.

Comment: Someone has an idea :p ?